# Calculate $\int \frac{\ln(15x^5)}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having some trouble with the following integral:

$$\int \frac{\ln(15x^5)}{x}$$

I separated the top into:

$$\int \frac{5\ln(x)+ \ln(15)}{x}$$

But, then I don't know where to go from there. I tried $u$ substitution by letting $u=\ln(x)$.

\begin{align}
\int 5u &+ \ln (15) \, du \\
\frac{5u^2}{2} &+ \ln(15)u \\
\frac{5(\ln(x))^2}{2}&+\ln(15)\ln(x)
\end{align}

Where am I going wrong? Can someone please provide some hints?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: $\ln xy=\ln x+\ln y\neq \ln x\cdot \ln y$

Comment: Whoops! I transferred that incorrectly from my paper to the question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong - just don't forget the arbitrary constant as well!

Comment: What makes you think that you're doing something wrong?

Comment: I thought I was done there so I looked at the answer and I was nowhere close so I thought that I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the given answer?

Comment: $\dfrac{{\left(5{\cdot}\ln\left(x\right)+\ln\left(15\right)\right)}^{2}}{10}$

Comment: You could also find this integral by substituting $u=\ln (15x^5)$, but I like your method better.

Comment: @gekkostate That's the same, modulo the additive constant. $(5\cdot\ln(x)+\ln(15))^2 = 25(\ln x)^2 + 10\ln x \ln 15 + (\ln 15)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int \frac{\ln(15x^5)}{x}\,dx & = \int \frac{5\ln(x)+ \ln(15)}{x}\,dx \\ \\ & = 5\int \frac{\ln x}{x} dx + \int \ln(15)x^{-1} \,dx\end{align}$$

You integrated the first portion correctly: $u = \ln x \implies du = \frac 1x\,dx$. And it so happens that you got the second integral correct too. (Indeed, there is no real need to separate the summed integrand into the sum of two integrals.)

Recall that $\ln(15)$ is nothing more than a constant.

There is some simplification you can do, if desired (using properties of the logarithm function). But your integration is just fine.

We could, alternatively, start from the beginning and set $$u = \ln(15x^5) \implies du = \dfrac{5\cdot 15x^4}{15x^5} \,dx = \frac 5x\,dx$$

$$\int \frac{\ln(15x^5)}{x}\,dx = \frac 15\int u\,du$$

and then go from there.

Comment: I haven't learned integration by parts. All I know is $u$ substitution and sorry about the mistake in the post. I transferred incorrect from paper to question.

Comment: No need here, sorry about that.

Comment: Glad to know that the integration was correct `:)`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @amWhy: You have very good patience too! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I agree with Amzoti, too +)